# problem reconstructing a string removing punctuation

Tags: c++

I am trying to write a program to strip the punctuation from a string. The input to the program should be a string of characters including punctuation; the output should be a string in which the punctuation is removed. I am using Visual Studio 2008 to compile and run the program. While executing it I am getting exception: "Debug Assertion Failed, Expression: string subscript out of range."

What 
am I doing wrong here?

```
int main()
{    
    string input;
    string output;

    getline(cin, input);

    string::size_type i = 0;
    for (string::size_type ix = 0; ix != input.size(); ++ix)
    {

        if (!ispunct(input[ix]))
        {
            output[i] = input[ix];
            ++i;
        }

    }


    cout << output << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You did not set a meaningful size to the `output` variable, so you are accessing elements that do not exist. You need to `output.push_back(input[ix]);`

Comment: +1: Since we know the size before the loop. We could re-size the output once rather than relying on the implementation to re-size it (potentially a couple of times). I can't claim I prefer it as I also missed it in my solution :-)

Answer (score 2):

You never allocated any space for the output `string`. Effectively, you're telling it to write into undefined memory locations, causing the assertion.

I can't tell if you want to remove the punctuation completely or just change it to say space, but assuming you want to remove it completely use this inside your `if` check:

`output.push_back(input[ix]);`

Answer (score 2):

Try the standard algorithms:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>
#include <functional>

int main()
{
    std::string input;
    std::string output;

    std::getline(std::cin, input);

    // This method copies items from the input container to the output container.
    // Unless the predicate is true (for the character being tested.
    // http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/remove_copy_if.html
    std::remove_copy_if(input.begin(), input.end(),            // Input container
                        std::back_inserter(output),            // Output (note the back inserter)
                        std::ptr_fun<int, int>(&std::ispunct)  // a function that tests for punct.
                       );

    std::cout << output << "\n";
}
```

Unlike the original code (which does not allocate space for output), this uses the std::back_inserter iterator to push_back() new elements into the output container (thus automatically generating the space required).

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
output += input[ix];
```

`output` is empty - `output[i]` is trying to access outside output's bounds. `std::string` will not automatically resize if you try to access out of bounds.